# Why do I get Memory Limit Exceeded?

Tags: python

I am trying to find 2 prime numbers that sum up to a certain integer N, specified by the user. But i get this error of MLE

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n%2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        return False
    sqr = int(n**0.5) + 1
    for divisor in range(3, sqr, 2):
        if n%divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True

class Solution:
    # @param A : integer
    # @return a list of integers
    def primesum(self, A):
        #Creating the list of prime numbers
        h_prime ={}
        # Initializing the hash table
        # looking for the prime numbers
        for i in range (2, long (A)):
            if ( is_prime(i)):
                h_prime [i] = A-i;
        # Checking if the compliment is also a prime
        #We go through it element by element
        for key in h_prime:
            if key in h_prime and A-key in h_prime:
                my_list = [ key, A-key]
                return my_list
```

Comment: How do you know the memory limit is exceeded? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Your code as-written doesn't ever execute since you never call a function. Please give us your actual [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the value of `A`?

Comment: `if key in h_prime` will always be `True`

Comment: Not sure why you store `h_prime[i] = A - i`, as you never use it. You could just have a `set` of primes.

Comment: Yes, there isn't a main function because I am writing this directly into an online platform.
A is the input number from the user. That is the one which I am trying to find the 2 other numbers that sum up to it.
ie: if the user inputs 4, I should return [2,2]

Comment: @PeterWood The error I am getting from the online platform says my solution compiles, but it has a run time error as follows:
"Memory Limit Exceeded. Your submission didn't complete in the allocated memory limit.
Your submission ran out of memory for the following input: A= 16777214 "
So, I am looking specifically for space / memory optimization

THanks a lot, and sorry for the delay

Comment: You're providing error messages from some service which we don't know. What are the requirements of the platform?

Comment: That is also quite a large number, `16777214 `. If you're using Python 2 [**`range`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) will allocate a `list` of size `16777214`. That might blow it for you. You can use [**`xrange`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) which creates a generator which is memory efficient. Python 3 [**`range`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is a generator so doesn't suffer from the problem.

Comment: The platform is www.interviewbit.com
Yes true, xrange might solve the problem. I will try it

Comment: I have tried `xrange` but it still giving me the same error

Comment: @Chada You updated both uses of `range`? Also, you should use the primes you've already found instead of going through all the integers for every candidate you're checking.

Comment: There are [1,077,871 primes below 16,777,214](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primes+below+16777214) so that might be blowing the memory constraints for you.

Comment: On my machine it almost immediately maxes the memory use at 280Mb. If I replace `range` with `xrange` it uses 13Mb.

Comment: I changed to use a `set` to store the primes and it used 4Mb

Comment: Actually, it doesn't need to be a `set`, a `list` is fine and it only uses about 3Mb

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asker doesn't seem to want to clarify, I'll answer in Go since I'm practicing it lately!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func isPrime(n int) bool {
    if n == 2 {
        return true
    } else if n%2 == 0 || n <= 1 {
        return false
    } else {
        sqrt := int(math.Floor(math.Sqrt(float64(n)))) + 1
        for divisor := 3; divisor < sqrt; divisor += 2 {
            if n%divisor == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}

func PrimesSum(n int) (int, int, error) {
    primes := make(map[int]struct{})
    for i := 2; i <= n; i++ {
        if isPrime(i) {
            primes[i] = struct{}{}
        }
    }
    for primeOne, _ := range primes {
        primeTwo := n - primeOne
        _, ok := primes[primeTwo]
        if ok {
            return primeOne, primeTwo, nil
        }
    }
    return 0, 0, fmt.Errorf("No prime sum for %v", n)
}

func main() {
    var i int
    fmt.Println("Enter a number to check: ")
    fmt.Print(">> ")
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&i)
    if err == nil {
        primeOne, primeTwo, err := PrimesSum(i)
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%v, %v\n", primeOne, primeTwo)
        } else {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Invalid input, %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you s much Adam! And sorry for the delay.
My code is actually correct logically, but it just exceeds the memory allocated by the platform in "Interviewbit" that is why I am looking for ways to improve the memory usage.